# powershell gui select list highlight

Tags: powershell

I hope there i can get an answer for this quick. Im populating a list box based on radio button being selected. I want the list box to highlight the row automatically so that when i click the button the relevant action can happen based on the selection. In this case it will be a sql server instance. See extract of code for adding it to ListBox1.

```
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
                    {

                #$NL = "`r`n"

                [void] $ListBox1.Items.Add($Server)
                       #$ListBox1.Items.selectedItem
                }
```

Comment: Hi, what do you want to automatically select in the list ?

Comment: Hi. The value that has just been added.

Comment: So if you add 9 lines in this loop the last one will be selected?

Comment: No all should be highlighted.

Comment: `$ListBox1.SelectAll()` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectall(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. But it doesnt work. Below error

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox] doesn't contain a method named 'SelectAll'.

Comment: Sorry this is the WPF class, not the Windows Forms one. See my answer for an example in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$listbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

$listbox.SelectionMode = "MultiSimple"

$listbox.Items.Add("item1") | Out-Null
$listbox.Items.Add("item2") | Out-Null
$listbox.Items.Add("item3") | Out-Null
$listbox.Items.Add("item4") | Out-Null

for($i = 0; $i -lt $listbox.Items.Count; $i++) {
    $listbox.SetSelected($i, $true)
}

$form.Controls.Add($listbox)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: If i want to display the values or basically do something with each one. How do i assign to a variable. I have something like this so far  $Button1.Text = "DoSomething"
 $Button1.BackColor = "Gray"

$Button1.Add_Click($DoSomething)

$DoSomething=

{
  foreach ($objItem in $ListBox1.value)
        {

}

Comment: I have changed my example, now you have a single `for` loop you can put in your `Add_Click` `scriptBlock`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look tomorrow UK time.